# django class list object and filtering lines

Tags: python, django

In Django I have a list of phone results. Here is a screenshot below:

[image: List details]

I am trying to query the list and get the result lines (like in querysets where I can use filter(condition).

In my example I want to get phonetype=='Cep' lines. I can do it by a for loop and if condition; however if there is a more decent way I want to learn it. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of basic `for` loop with `if` condition you can use [List Comprehension](https://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php).

For your use-case it should look like something like this:

```
results = [phone for phone in phones if phone.get('phonetype')=='Cep']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However your are still using for loop and if statement. Do you know  putting it in one line has a better performance and run time?

Comment: List Comprehension perform better because you don’t need to load the append attribute off of the list and call it as a function. You can read more here [Efficiency of list comprehensions](http://blog.cdleary.com/2010/04/efficiency-of-list-comprehensions/)